# update mysql table with php array

Tags: php, mysql

I've a PHP multidimensional array like this:

```
username_1, user_state, user_score, user_views, ...
username_2, user_state, user_score, user_views, ...
username_3, user_state, user_score, user_views, ...
username_4, user_state, user_score, user_views, ...
...................................................
```

I could write a loop in PHP, but with several hundred users, I don't want it to hit mysql db for each user. Instead, I want to somehow pass the array to MySQL and have it take care of all the updates.

Now, in SQL Server, I could write a stored procedure to take care of all this, but what would be the most efficient/simplest way to take care of this in MySQL?

(I did google it up, but most of them loop in PHP instead of MySQL.)

Comment: `Mysql` also supports `stored procedure.`

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to avoid stored procedure. I'll tell you one solution. Mysql supports inserting multiple records in a single query. So you do one thing write a for loop in your php program and create one big query to insert into database and after that for loop run that query.

Comment: i think its possible. can you please update some data? And please show me how you wanna update that

Comment: Should be possible, another way is to divide single querys by `;` and send them to SQL-Server as a big single string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql="update tablename set username_1='demo', user_state='active', user_score='100', user_views='20' where id='1'";
     mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use REPLACE instead of UPDATE which has the same syntax as INSERT (so you can process multiple records in a single query) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html
2. You may also use prepared statements : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php